# console output on gui

Tags: java, mysql

I have problem with console output. I did search for one day now and i still can't fix the problem. I have tried adding text on `JTextArea` manually and it works, so gui should be fine. IF i change code to `System.out.println(s)`, it will writte in console successfully. Here is my code:

```
public static void runSystemCommand(String command) {

  String message=null;
  int i=0;
  while (i<1){

    try {
                    gui area=new gui();
                   // ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    areaField=new JTextArea();
                     sarray  = new String [500];

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String s = "";



        // reading output stream of the command
        while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                            area.jTextArea.append(s+ "\n"); //this doesnt work..

        }
                    Thread.sleep(9000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     i++;
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: so far, all you've mentioned is that it works successfully. so, what's the issue?

Comment: i cant see it on gui jTextArea

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: You need to tell us what the issue is (+ any error codes), and what you've tried so far to fix it.

Comment: Is it intentionally named area.jTextArea?

Comment: guys i will give u full code with gui , issue is i can get this only write in console with System.out.println(s). If i want to append it to jTextArea it doesnt work

Comment: @LoganKulinski Oh yes of course. You cannot name objects unintentionally.

Comment: i have added all code, thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending to the wrong `JTextArea`.
In your `pingmain` class you create a new instance of `gui` which is never shown to the user. In this invisible instance you correctly add the text to the textarea.
If you instead add a `gui area` parameter to your `runSystemCommand` method and give `this` as second arguemnt to the method call in `gui`, you will see your output in your textarea.

Comment: Thank you so much we've been trying to fix this problem for ages.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have an empty string `String s = "";` try to assign some string to `s` like this:

```
    String s = "some value";
    area.jTextArea.append(s+ "\n");
```

Comment: @swipeales for a good practice put these in the top of class // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnSubmit;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jCbx;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
public javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea;

Comment: yeah its auto from netbeans

Comment: Well, there are many bad practices in this short code, beginning with lowercase class names. But we should not judge this here. :-D